# tfs addWorkItemSaveListener is not getting events

Tags: sdk, tfs

I am adding a TFS WorkItemSaveListener but not getting any Event on saving workitem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Connecting to Project
        final TFSTeamProjectCollection collection = ConsoleSettings.connectToTFS();

        // Creating an object of listener
        WorkItemSaveListenerImpl listener = new WorkItemSaveListenerImpl();

        //Adding the listener
        collection.getWorkItemClient().getEventEngine().addWorkItemSaveListener(listener);

        for(;;) {
            // keeping the program alive
            try {

                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only really guessing here as I don't know the java sdk. But is it possible that the addWorkItemSaveListener event is only triggered for work items changed by that particular work item client?

You may need to setup a soap subscription, or write a server plugin instead.

**C# to setup a soap subscription**

Sorry it's for the wrong event, but it may be enough to give you an idea.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(txtServerUrl.Text));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
IEventService eventSrv = tpc.GetService(typeof(IEventService)) as IEventService;
DeliveryPreference delPref = new DeliveryPreference();
delPref.Address = "http://" + System.Environment.MachineName + ":8001/CheckInNotify";
delPref.Schedule = DeliverySchedule.Immediate;
delPref.Type = DeliveryType.Soap;
subscriptionId = eventSrv.SubscribeEvent(System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" +     System.Environment.UserName, "CheckInNotify", "", delPref);
```